# GOPATH not installed when using AUR

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman, aur

I am trying to install `supabase-git`, but it's happened on many other packages. During the build stage, I get this:

```bsh
==> Starting build()...
missing $GOPATH
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
Finished with result: exit-code
```

I've run `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` (/home/pineapplefan/go) and it contains /pkg

Any idea why it's failing, and how do I fix it?

(Command being run is `sudo pamac install supabase-git`)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the PKGBUILD manually, and prepend `GOPATH=$HOME/go` to `go build`

In other words,

```
build() {
  cd cli
  go build \
    -gcflags "all=-trimpath=${PWD}" \
    -asmflags "all=-trimpath=${PWD}" \
    -ldflags "-extldflags ${LDFLAGS}" \
    -o $_pkgname
}
```

becomes

```
build() {
  cd cli
  GOPATH=$HOME/go go build \
    -gcflags "all=-trimpath=${PWD}" \
    -asmflags "all=-trimpath=${PWD}" \
    -ldflags "-extldflags ${LDFLAGS}" \
    -o $_pkgname
}
```

Then do `makepkg -si`